# Put a lang function inside of a php string

Tags: php, mysql, string, function, str-replace

Trying to do a translation of my MySQL DB to PHP.

Here's the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT Name, Price FROM utf WHERE Name LIKE 'K%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class=\"CSSTableGenerator style=\"width:600px;height:150px;\"><table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th></tr></div>";
    // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = str_replace('K', 'Karambit', $row['Name']);
    echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$row["Price"]." ".$row["Trend"]."</td></tr>";
}
   echo "</table>";
```

So Select, Filter by signature character, and then translate.

Now, I have a lang.php file which has the translations.

Here it is:

```
<?php
function lang($phrase){
    static $lang = array(
        'ba' => 'Bayonet',
        'ka' => 'Karambit'
    );
    return $lang[$phrase];
}
?>
```

How do I put it in this line:

```
$name = str_replace('K', 'Karambit', $row['Name']);
```

and replace `'ka' => 'Karambit'` with `'Karambit'`?

Non of these have worked:

```
//attempt 1
$name = str_replace('K', 'lang('ka');', $row['Name']);
//attempt 2
$name = str_replace('K', '$lang('ka');', $row['Name']);
//attempt 3
$word = echo lang('ka');
$name = str_replace('K', '$word', $row['Name']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put [function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) calls in quotes, just use:

```
$name = str_replace('K', lang('ka'), $row['Name']);
                       //^^^^^^^^^^ See here
```

Also to give you another option:

You can store your `search => replace` values into an array like this:

```
$searchReplace = [
    "ba" => "Bayonet",
    "ka" => "Karambit",
];
```

And then you can simply use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to replace it, e.g.

```
$name = strtr($row['Name'], $searchReplace);
```

Comment: @ParsaPierre You're welcome. (I also added another alternative, which maybe simplifies your code)